# Use multiple counter-reset rules on one element

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I have two different CSS files, and I want `body` to reset two counters:

This file is linked before:

```
body {
    counter-reset: counter-one;
}
```

and this one after

```
body {
    counter-reset: counter-two; /* Doesn't work, because it overrides the first rule! */
}
```

I can't make a single rule with both counters, they need to be in separate files.
How can I reset the two counters, **and only modify the second file**?
If possible, it should also work with any number of counters and any number of files.
Using JS (that only access document) is possible.

This works:

```
/* First file*/
body {
    --counter-reset: counter-one;
}


/* Second file*/
body {
    counter-reset: counter-two var(--counter-reset);
}
```

but I would like the first file to only have `counter-reset: counter-one;`

I also considered wrapping all `body`'s content in other elements, but that's not convenient.

Comment: Can you give a little context about where each counter is used? Are they both used on the same page? Do they both increment at the same element? If they both increment at the same elements, or are used on different pages, you could use the same counter for both.

Comment: Alternatively you'd probably be better off applying the resets on a different element. If each of the counters has a different closest common ancestor you can use that to reset each.

Comment: @JakeSidSmith The second file will be some default styling, and the first file is created by the user. In some cases the user needs to reset counters (this is likely to happen on body) on an element where the second file resets another. The user is not supposed to be aware of these things, this is why I need to change the syntax for him as little as possible.

Comment: If you have no control over where the user resets the counter then I think your only option would be to use JavaScript to add/combine any clashing styles. :/